# Find the distance between these two open balls

Tags: real-analysis

For the metric space described below, find the distance between two different open balls of the same radius r if both balls are subsets of a closed ball of radius r.

The metric space was given by the previous problem which said "In set X of all possible sequences $x=(n_1,n_2,...), y=(m_1,m_2,...)$ let $k_0(x,y)$ be the smallest index $k$ such that $n_k \neq m_k$. Then we had to prove a bunch of things which may be useful here

a) $\rho(x,y) = k_0(x,y)^{-1}$  is a metric

b) triangle inequality is strengthened as $\rho(x,z) \leq$ max{$p(x,y), \rho(y,z)$}

c) for any open ball $B_r(x) = \bar{B}_r(x)$

d) $B_r(x)=B_r(y)$ for any $y \in B_r(x)$

e) if two balls have a common point then one of them is a subset of the other ball

f) $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence iff $\rho(x_n, x_{n+1}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

g) X is complete and separable

I've been able to prove most of these so far, but I'm not asking about them, I just think they might be useful for this question.  I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

If property d) holds, then all three balls in question are the same (also using c)).

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for both questions!  I've been staring at this for hours thinking about how its not possible to have two different open balls here so its good to hear someone else say that its not.  So is the answer the distance is 0 or just that this isn't possible?

Comment: Indeed, the distance is zero. Here is why it should not be counter-intuitive for this particular metric space. If two points $x,y$ are in the same ball, then this just means that the first, say $k$, entries are identical. Then, if $z$ is in a ball around $y$, its first $k$ entries are identical to those of $y$, hence of $x$. Thus,  whenever you have a chain $\rho(x_1,x_2)=r$ and $\rho(x_i,x_{i+1})=r$, then all the $x_i$ have the same first $k$ entries and are in the same ball.

Comment: To the proposer: In metric spaces in general we cannot always speak of "the" center or "the" radius of an open or closed ball. With the usual notation $B(x,r)=\{y: \rho (y,x)<r\}$ we can have $B(x,r)=B(x',r') $ with $ x\ne x' $  and $ r\ne r'.$

Comment: Admittedly, I was a little imprecise. My comment provides an answer, though. It can be phrased with points having distance less than $r$ (equal sign should be less than) and doesn't need centers or radii. Thus, in fact, property d) holds in more generality.